# Orientdb sql auto increment: id is always null (sql batch, update increment, variables)

Tags: sql, variables, batch-processing, auto-increment, orientdb

I was looking at another question in stackoverflow regarding auto increment fields in orientdb, where one of the answers was to create our own vertex with counter field.

However, when I'm trying to execute the following code (both java api and console script batch), It is not working.

Do note however that the id is returned good (did some debug attempts, returning the id variable only), and the vertex is created.

However, the vertex id is *always* null (unless I set it explicit, that is).

The script:

```
script sql
LET id = UPDATE CCounter INCREMENT value=1 RETURN AFTER $current WHERE name='session'
LET csession = CREATE VERTEX CDate SET id=$id.result, meet_date='2015-01-01 15:23:00'
end
```

I tried playing around with $id and $current , but nothing seems to work.
Currently I am doing it in a 2-transaction mode; one to get the id, and another to create the vertex. I really hope there is a better way though.

P.S.
I am using version 2.0-M2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in a comment to Lvca, the answer was:

(1) Change the field name. Id seems to be reserved (ish). It's probably possible to still bypass it and use a field named 'id', but I didn't want to mess around with it.
(2) From some reason, the result was a collection (shown as '[id]'). It took me some time to figure it out, but I just had to choose the first value from it.
(3) Also, there are 2 'values' here. One of the field ($current.value), and the second one(not sure where it's coming from).

Final solution that works:

```
script sql
LET id = UPDATE CCounter INCREMENT value = 1 RETURN AFTER $current.value WHERE name='session'
LET csession = CREATE VERTEX CDate SET data_id=$id[0].value, meet_date='2015-01-01 15:23:00'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should execute

```
LET csession = CREATE VERTEX CDate SET id=$id.value, meet_date='2015-01-01 15:23:00'
```

Note the $id.value in place of $id.result.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work either. It result in a null value insrted into id. I did figure out the problem(s) though; First, id seems to be a reserved keyword or something, so I had to change the field name. Second, the returned value was a collection, still not sure why, so I had to use [0]. Thanks though.

Comment: You're right, with RETURN clause the UPDATE statement returns the resultset of updated records.